# Approaches to solving $y''(1-x^2)-2xy'+2y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know it could be done via power series but what other methods are there?

Comment: -2xy' sorry, my bad

Comment: Please, do not change the question after answers have been posted. Reset this question as it was before and ask another question with the new problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=x z$ and the equation becomes
$$2\left(1-2 x^2\right) z'-x \left(x^2-1\right) z''=0$$ Reduction of order $p=z'$ gives
$$2\left(1-2 x^2\right) p-x \left(x^2-1\right) p'=0$$ which is separable. So
$$p=\frac{c_1}{x^2 \left(1-x^2\right)}=c_1 \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2 (x+1)}-\frac{1}{2 (x-1)} \right)$$ which is simple.

Integrating
$$z=c_1\left(-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2} \log (1-x)+\frac{1}{2} \log (x+1)\right)+c_2$$
$$y=c_1\left(-1-\frac{1}{2} x\log (1-x)+\frac{1}{2}x \log (x+1)\right)+c_2 x$$

Comment: is there a lineraly independent solution?

Comment: This answer gives two linearly independent solutions.

Comment: @CakesCakesCakes. I edited to finish the solution

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: oh no, I think y missed something

Comment: @CakesCakesCakes. You are welcome ! Glad to help you.

Comment: It should've been a third order, my bad. So, it should be two reduction of orders, right?